# Whether there has open source successful libraries to implement search function like my blueprint?

Tags: search, text-search, react, file-search

I am tring to create a React component for search, the UI like below:

[image]

the directory area displays directories tree, every file can open a page.
I want to search the file and its page content.

but in my experience, I've never done anything like this before, please tell me whether there has open source successful libraries to implement it?

before ask this question, I have know about elasticsearch, algolia, etc.